# Excel Not Responding after trying to run code to copy data and send an email

Tags: excel, vba, email

Basically I have 7 cells that could be populated with text (b2, b4, b6, b8, b10, b12 and b14). I want to the code to check each of the cells to see if they have a value and send only the cells that do have a value in an email. For formatting purposes the cells pasted into the email need to have one empty cell in between and the cells need to be kept in the order they are in originally, just without the unnecessary blank cells.

I've never officially learned VBA I've only taught myself on a case by case scenario so there could be an easy solution that I'm missing. Often I can debug and find the problem but in this case Excel completely freezes and turns "Not Responding". I have a feeling that means I've got a loop somewhere unresolved but I don't really understand how. The code -seems- to run up until Range("A2").Value = Line(LineCount1). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub SingleEmail()
Dim LineCount1 As Integer
Dim LineCount2 As Integer
Dim LineCount3 As Integer
Dim LineCount4 As Integer
Dim LineCount5 As Integer
Dim LineCount6 As Integer
Dim LineCount7 As Integer
Dim NumOfLines As Integer

Range("A2", "A14").ClearContents

LineCount1 = 2 
Range("A2").Value = Line(LineCount1)

LineCount2 = 2 + LineCount1
Range("A4").Value = Line(LineCount2)

LineCount3 = 2 + LineCount2
Range("A6").Value = Line(LineCount3)

LineCount4 = 2 + LineCount3
Range("A8").Value = Line(LineCount4)

LineCount5 = 2 + LineCount4
Range("A10").Value = Line(LineCount5)

LineCount6 = 2 + LineCount5
Range("A12").Value = Line(LineCount6)

LineCount7 = 2 + LineCount6
Range("A14").Value = Line(LineCount7)

NumOfLines = Range("n3").Value

If Range("A2") <> "" Then
    Range("A2", "A" & NumOfLines).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = ""
      .Item.To = "personalemailaddress@Someplace.com"
      .Item.CC = ""
      .Item.Subject = "Email Subject"
      .Item.send
    End With
End If

End Sub




Function Line(ByRef LineCount As Integer) As String
Line = ""
Do While Line = "" Or LineCount < 13
If Range("B" & LineCount).Value <> "" Then
    Line = Range("B" & LineCount).Value
Else
    LineCount = LineCount + 2
End If
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Is it possible the else portion of your Do While loop never executes?

Comment: In the test area I was running this code it should have looped through the Else statement once. Cell b2 is currently blank and cell b4 has text. If cell b2 had text in it than the Else section would not execute because instead it would enter the first section of the if statement. Once the variable Line is anything other than nothing then the function is supposed to stop looping and return the result. Do you know of any way I might test it to find out if it's working the way I think it is?

Comment: Step through it using the debugger?

Comment: I've got that working now, but I need to learn to use the debugger. The only way I've used it so far is when it pops up an error while running the code I can see where the error occurred and google search it. I'm assuming this is not how the debugger is meant to be used, haha.

Comment: You can use `F8` to go through your code line by line, and see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

If `B4` has value and `B2` is blank then this `While` loop become infinite. the LineCount is Stuck on 4, hence no overflow. That's why your code freezes.

Why are you running a loop in the first place. You can simply assign the values like this `Range("A2:A14").Value =Range("B2:B14").Value`
 As per your comment, you need to use `And` operator in place of `OR`
`Do While Line = "" And LineCount < 13` now the loop will exit if line <> "" or LineCount > 14

Comment: Isn't the loop supposed to stop when either the variable line <> "" or linecount >13. In this instance linecount only goes up to 4, but the variable Line is = the value in cell b4 so the loop should exit, right?

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try. Originally I did have the code written without the loop, though I didn't actually test it out at all. I decided to change it though because I'm trying to force myself to learn how they work better so that I can write shorter code. I was trying to figure out how to do the first section of the code (LineCount1 = 2 
Range("A2").Value = Line(LineCount1)) as a loop with arrays but I don't know how that works well enough or if it's even reasonably possible.

Comment: Thank you. Changing Or to And seemed to work. And thinking on it now, i do understand that logic. Now I'm having trouble with the email section. For some reason it's copying and emailing all the cells on my active worksheet. I've got the email code working in another window when I'm just trying to copy cells b2 to b14 and send them, but the email code I've written here isn't working how it's supposed to. Any suggestion?

Comment: Honestly, I have never used Envelope method. I always use Outlook object to send e-mail.

Comment: Unfortunately my work computer will not allow me to install anything currently, that includes Excel add-ins...